# Не работает метод .split()

Tags: javascript, split

```
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
function digi(){
var n = inp.value;
var digit = parseInt(n, 2);
var modified = String(digit);
    var arra = digit.split(',');
for(var i = 2; i < n; i++){
    console.log(digit);
    for(var j = 0; j < arra.length; j++){
        if(j == 1 ){
            var opp = [];
            var arr = opp.push(j);
        } else if(j == 0){
            var pop = [];
            var arr2 = pop.push(j);
        }
        if(arr.length > arr2.length){
        console.log(n);
    }

    }
    }
}

digi(55);
```

Здравствуйте, не могу понять, почему не работает split
В консоли пишет, что *split is not a function*
Пробовал вместо записи значения в переменную n записывать число прямо в параметр функции, не помогло

Comment: у вас переменная digit какой тип ? точно стринг ? проверьте вручную

Comment: попробуйте digit.toString() там, где присваиваете modified

Comment: переменая возвращает NaN или что то типо того и поэтому функция split ругается

Comment: Ничего из этого не помогло

Answer (score 1):

```
var digit = parseInt(n, 2);
var modified = String(digit);
var arra = digit.split(',');
```

`digit`, на которую применяется `split()` - число (см. первая строка).
`split()` надо прикладываться к `modified` из второй строки:

```
var digit = parseInt(n, 2);
var modified = String(digit);
var arra = modified.split(',');
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
function digi(){
var n = inp.value; 
var digit = parseInt(n, 10);  
    var arra = n.split(',');
    console.log(arra);
for(var i = 2; i < n; i++){
    console.log(digit);
    for(var j = 0; j < arra.length; j++){
        if(j == 1 ){
            var opp = [];
            var arr = opp.push(j);
        } else if(j == 0){
            var pop = [];
            var arr2 = pop.push(j);
        }
        if(arr.length > arr2.length){
        console.log(n);
    }

    }
    }
}


digi(55);
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="5,444">
```